# Getting an error when declaring Hash on Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am currently learning Ruby, and on the tutorial the way to declare an hash is like this:

```
states {
  "Pennsylvania" => "PA",
  "Quebec" => "MTL"
}

puts states["Pennsylvania"]
```

The error message gives me that:

```
[Running] ruby "c:\Users\ilyes\OneDrive\Bureau\Concordia\2nd Year\Fall 2019\COMP 348\RubyPrograms\practice.rb"
c:/Users/ilyes/OneDrive/Bureau/Concordia/2nd Year/Fall 2019/COMP 348/RubyPrograms/practice.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
  :Pennsylvania => "PA",
                ^~
c:/Users/ilyes/OneDrive/Bureau/Concordia/2nd Year/Fall 2019/COMP 348/RubyPrograms/practice.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
  :Pennsylvania => "PA",
                       ^

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.171 seconds
```

I don't understand why since I have been following what he says exactly
I am currently using VSC since atom doesn't work at all.

Comment: missing the assignment equal sign (`states = {` instead of `states {`)

Comment: @SimpleLime yep I feel dumb now haha
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" and  "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" including all linked pages. The steps listed in those will go a long way toward avoiding this sort of mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ambiguity between blocks and `Hash` literals when passing a `Hash` literal as the only argument to message send without using parentheses.

I.e. when you write something like

```rb
foo {
  # something
}
```

It could either mean that you are sending the message `foo` and passing a block, or passing a `Hash`. It will be interpreted by Ruby as passing a block, so Ruby expects `# something` to be an *expression* or a sequence of expressions.

In order to make it clear to Ruby that you mean to pass a `Hash`, you should use parentheses to make it clear that the curly braces are inside the argument list:

```rb
states({
  "Pennsylvania" => "PA",
  "Quebec" => "MTL"
})

puts states["Pennsylvania"]
# PA
```

Of course, this assumes a suitable definition of `states`, something like this:

```rb
states_cache = {}
define_method(:states) do |states = (states_not_passed = true; nil)|
  return states_cache.dup if states_not_passed
  states_cache = states_cache.merge(states).freeze
end
```

Comment: interesting.... are not having paranteces optional in ruby?

Comment: No, parentheses are not not really optional in Ruby. You can leave them out in many cases and Ruby will still understand but not always.